# Prolog remove all duplicates function

Tags: syntax, prolog

I have a code that SHOULD work in theory, yet it does not. I have remove function that removes all occurrences of a and returns the new list. I call this at each step and pass the new list, while adding the head. here is my code, which returns false.

```
remv(a, [], []).
remv(a, [H|T], X) :- H=a, remv(a, T, X).
remv(a, [H|T],[H|X]):- remv(a, T, X).

%4
remvdub([],[]).
remvdub([H|T],[H|X]) :- remvdub(remv(H,T,A),X).
```

can someone explain what the issue is?

Comment: Prolog uses predicates, not functions. Predicates express relations and are always true or false. You are assuming that `remv/3` returns a list, but it's not the case. You should try to modify the second rule: `remvdub([H|T], [H|X]):-remv(H,T,T2), remvdub(T2,X).`. The rules has the following meaning: for a list `[H|T]`, the list `[H|X]` is the initial one without doubles if there is a list `T2` which is `T` without any occurence of `H` and `X` is the list `T2` without any doubles.

Comment: that line is still not returning a correct answer. it is still returning false

Comment: i see what you did though. For some reason it is not working

Comment: You have other problems: you are using atom `a` instead of a variable in the first predicate: `remv/3`.

Comment: And you should use a cut operator (`!`) in the first rule after `H=A` so you wouldn't get wrong solutions too.

Comment: i wish you would have given this as an answer so i could upvote it! thank you so much! i totally forgot about the lower case issue. And you explained the function / predicate issue.

Comment: Two more things regarding style, not correctness: you can use an anonymous variable in the first rule: `remv(_, [], [])` as you are not using that variable (that should get you rid of the "Singleton variable" warning). In the second rule you can unify the first argument with the head of the list directly like this: `remv(E,[E|T],X):-!,...`.

Answer (score 1):

You are treating `rev` as a function, expecting it to "return" a list w/ `H`'s removed.  In fact, it will bind `A` to such a list, so that is what should be the first argument to `remvdub`.  That is:

```
remvdub([H|T],[H|X]) :- remv(H,T,A), remvdub(A,X).
```

Comment: ok, so I guess i'm still confused. So if i pass a , how would i use the head and the tail? thank you for the response btw